# How to write a perl if statement that tests how many times a string is found using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl script that contains an if statement, and I want this if statement to check if a string is found via regex a certain number of times in a saved string. I would like to do this in a single line if possible, imagined like so:

```
$saved_string = "This abc is my abc test abc";
if( #something_to_denote_counting ($saved_string =~ /abc/) == 3)
{
    print "abc was found in the saved string exactly 3 times";
}
else
{
    print "abc wasn't found exactly 3 times";
}
```

...But I don't know what I need to do in that if statement to check for the number of times the regex matches. Can someone please tell me if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ( 3 == ( () = $saved_string =~ /abc/g ) ) {
    print "abc was found in the saved string exactly 3 times";
}
```

To get the count, you need to use /g in list context.  So you could do:

```
@matches = $saved_string =~ /abc/g;
if ( @matches == 3 ) {
```

but perl provides a little help to make it easier; a list assignment, placed in scalar context (such as is provided by `==`), returns the count of elements on the *right* side of the assignment.  This enables code like:

```
while ( my ($key, $value) = each %hash ) {
```

So you could do:

```
if ( 3 == ( @matches = $saved_string =~ /abc/g ) ) {
```

but using an array isn't even necessary; assigning into an empty list is sufficient (and has become an idiom wherever you need to execute code in list context but only get a count of results).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me what the '()' as in '() = $saved_string' is for?

Comment: @jake9115, In detail, `()` is a placeholder that forces the following assignment to be a list assignment operator. The list assignment operator evaluates its operands in list context, and it returns the number of things returned by its right-hand side when used in scalar context. See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).

Comment: @jake9115, Tweaked explanaton and fixed the link

Answer (score 3):

Save matches to anon array reference, dereference it using `@{}` and compare to number,

```
if( @{[ $saved_string =~ /abc/g ]} == 3) {
  print "abc was found in the saved string exactly 3 times";
}
```